# Examples of modules satisfying $(0:_{M/N}r):=\{m+N\in M/N:r(m+N)\in N\}=\{m\in M:rm\in N\}=(N:_{M}r)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be a ring with unity and $M$ a left $R$-module.  Define the annihilator of $r\in R$ with respect to $M$ as $$(0:_Mr)=\{m\in M:rm=0\}.~~~~~~~~~~~~(1)$$   Similarly, for any submodule $N$ of $M$, we can define the annihilator of $r$ with respect to quotient $M/N$ as  $$(0:_{M/N}r):=\{m+N\in M/N:r(m+N)\in N\}=\{m\in M:rm\in N\}=(N:_{M}r).~~~~(2)$$

My questions:

Are there examples of modules or ring element(s) or conditions for which property (2) holds?  In particular, for a case when $rm\neq 0$.

Comment: Property (2) cannot be an equality since $M/N \cap M = \emptyset$.  I think the best you can say is something like $\pi^{-1}(0:_{M/N}r) = (N:_Mr)$ where $\pi : M \to M/N$ is the canonical map... Is that what you meant?

Comment: I don't understand the point that $M/N\cap N=\emptyset$.  Besides, I am still comfortable  with the situation $(0:_{M/N}r)\subseteq (N:_Mr)$.  Though, I used to think that they are equal sets.

Comment: @mariam The first set is a set of subsets of $M$, the second set is a subset of $M$.   They are not subsets of each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you know is $m+N\in (0:_{M/N} r)\iff rm\in N\iff m\in(N:_M r)$, which does not mean the same thing as the equality you wrote.

It would be correct to write $(N:_M r)/N=(0:_{M/N} r)$, though.

As far as I can see that holds for all rings and modules.

As for a nontrivial case, why not keep things simple and just try $R=\mathbb Z$ and $M=\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$, $N=2\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$.

With $r=2$ you have, for example,

$$ (N:_M r)=M $$

$$
(0:_{M/N} r)= M/N
$$

and $m=1 +4\mathbb Z$ is nonzero such that $rm\neq 0+4\mathbb Z$.